# link_to helper weird url

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

Hello everyone I was wondering how I can get rid of this ugly url that was generated when I clicked a link on my website. It looks like this:

```
http://www.imaaroncs.com/about?as=AboutMe&class=changeMe&controler=welcome
```

I want it to just say about but I do not know how to do it with the link_to rails helper this is what I have so far:

```
<li class="navbar-brand"><%= link_to "About Me", class: "changeMe",controler: "welcome", as: "AboutMe", action: "about"%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a few parameters you don't need (the ones after ? are being interpreted as additional query params)

```
<%= link_to "About Me", action: "about" %>
```

Comment: Great. Another thing, it's not that common to use the action name as the way to describe the url. Perfectly OK, but there may be a method created from your routes file.  You can look at all the methods by doing a `rake routes` on the command line.  The method might be something like `about_path`, then that would be a little hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the literal hash:

```
<%= link_to "About Me", {class: "changeMe", controller: "welcome", as: "AboutMe", action: "about"} %>
```

PS. Also, there is double `l` in controller. You have one.